# sumUp each array of an multidimensional array

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I want to sum up each i array and store it as an element of a new array.

I expect to get int[] sumUp={10,30}
What am I doing wrong?
My result is instead {0,10}

```
    int[][] matrixOne= {{1,2,3,4},{10,20}};

    int [] sumUp=new int[matrixOne.length];
    int toSum=0;

    for(int i=0;i<matrixOne.length;i++) {

        sumUp[i]=toSum;

        for(int j=0;j<matrixOne[i].length;j++) {
            toSum+=matrixOne[i][j];

        }
    }
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sumUp));
```

Comment: typo: `toSum+=matrixOne[i][j];` -> `sumUp[i]+=matrixOne[i][j];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others are pointing out you are storing your sum in `toSum` not `sumUp`  in your inner loop.

If you want to avoid these mistakes, and you are using Java 8, you could simply do something like:

```
int[][] matrixOne= {{1,2,3,4},{10,20}};

int [] sumUp=new int[matrixOne.length];

for(int i=0;i<matrixOne.length;i++) {
  sumUp[i] = Arrays.stream(matrixOne[i]).sum();
}
```

You could even stream and map the outer array, but it becomes a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You're storing the result before you sum the numbers.

**EDIT**: forgot to reset the sum

```
toSum = 0;

for(int j=0;j<matrixOne[i].length;j++) {
  toSum+=matrixOne[i][j];
}

sumUp[i]=toSum;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer a `stream` on the `int[][]` which you can `map` (and `stream()` to `sum()`) in one pass. Like,

```
int[][] matrixOne = { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 10, 20 } };
int[] sumUp = Arrays.stream(matrixOne).mapToInt(x -> Arrays.stream(x).sum()).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sumUp));
```

Outputs (as expected)

```
[10, 30]
```